# Difference between on and out on

Tags: meaning

What is difference between **Put the glasses on the table** and **Put the glasses out on the table**?

Comment: _Out_ would be used in case the speaker wanted to make sure the glasses are placed away (_out_) from other things on the table, therefore making them more visible. Alternatively, _out_ here can mean that the table is far away from the current location where the speech is taking place.

Comment: @JohnLawler although your answer is different by what lawrence said in previous comment, but I just decided to trust you. Please write your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Feel free to accept it without rewriting or checking any boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **put something out** *phrasal verb*
>   Lay something out ready for use.
>   ‘she put out glasses and paper napkins’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/put_something_out)

The phrase 'put the glasses on the table' refers simply to placing something somewhere. The phrase on its own doesn't even hint at a reason for placing them there.

On the other hand, 'putting the glasses *out* on the table' tends to carry the connotation of preparing them for use, for example, as part of the process of setting the table for guests.

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: +1 This was certainly the standard colloquial usage at my house when I was growing up (in Texas): "Should I set the table?" "Yes, and don't forget to put the glasses out, too." Or: "Are the glasses already out on the table?" The wording didn't refer to making the glasses more visible, nor did it imply that the table was far away. If anything, the "out" referred to "out of the cabinet" where glasses were stored between meals.